# GUI Jlist ItemListener

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlist

I am trying to create a JList with some elements and when the user selects an element another JList will appear in the window. Then, if the user selects an element of the other list a text area will appear in the window. Here is what I have made so far :

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ProductsList extends JFrame implements ItemListener {


private JLabel availableDev;
private JComboBox avDevBox
private JTextArea itemDetails;
private JList Items;
private JList devicesForSale;
private JList imandSJList;
private JList applJList;
private JList gamJList;

public ProductsList() {

    String[] avDevicesListItems = {"Image and Sound", "Appliance", "Gaming"};
    ArrayList<imageAndSound> iasList = new ArrayList<imageAndSound>;
    ArrayList<Appliance> applianceList = new ArrayList<Appliance>;
    ArrayList<Gaming> gamingList = new ArrayList<Gaming>;

    //construct components
    availableDev = new JLabel ("Available Devices");
    avDevicesList = new JList (avDevicesListItems);
    itemDetails = new JTextArea (5, 5);
    avDevBox = new JComboBox (avDevicesListItems);
    devicesForSale = new JList(devList);
    imandSJList = new JList(iasList);
    applJList = new JList(applianceList);
    gamJList = new JList(gamingList);

    avDevBox.addItemListener(this);

    //adjust size and set layout
    setPreferredSize (new Dimension (944, 574));
    setLayout (null);

    //add components
    add (availableDev);
    add (avDevicesList);
    add (itemDetails);
    add (avDevBox);
    add(devicesForSale);

    //set component bounds
    availableDev.setBounds (35, 0, 100, 25);
    avDevBOx.setBounds (25, 30, 120, 25);
    itemDetails.setBounds (245, 225, 265, 215);

    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        int choice = avDevBox.getSelectedIndex();
        if (choice = 0) {
            add(imandSJList);
            imandSJList.addItemListener(this);
        }
        else if (choice = 1){
            add(applJList);
            applJList.addItemListener(this);
        }
        else {
            add(gamJList);
            gamJList.addItemListener(this);
        }
    }   


public static void main (String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame ("Products List");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation (JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add (new MyPanel());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible (true);
    TV tv1 = new TV("LCD","28","720p","HDMI/DVI","11235","AT142","2015","SONY",500,5); //Creates object of class TV
    TV tv2 = new TV("LED","32","1080p","HDMI/DVI","15394","AT168","2016","SAMSUNG",1000,0); //Creates object of class TV
    bluerayDVD dvd = new bluerayDVD("DVD","720p","DVD-RW","15642","TT172","2015","SONY",400,100); //Creates object of class bluerayDVD
    bluerayDVD blueray = new bluerayDVD("blueray","1080p","BD-R","18412","TT100","2015","SONY",500,1000); //Creates object of class bluerayDVD
    Camera cam1 = new Camera("DSLR","50","stable","x5","2","19785","TC137","2016","SONY",600,50); //Creates object of class Camera
    Camera cam2 = new Camera("compact,","40","stable","x7","1","16783","TC108","2016","SONY",700,70); //Creates object of class Camera
    Console c1 = new Console("PS4","RGEN","1080p","Dolby","1 TB","15641","TG142","2016","SONY",400,80); //Creates object of class Console
    Console c2 = new Console("XBOX","RGEN2","1080p","Dolby Digital","2 TB","13424","TG123","2016","MICROSOFT",400,10); //Creates object of class Console
    Refrigerator f1 = new Refrigerator("Single door","C++","5kg","2kg","28756","TF357","2016","BOSS",1500,10); //Creates object of class Refrigerator
    Refrigerator f2 = new Refrigerator("Double door","C++","8kg","4kg","26756","TF382","2016","SIEMENS",500,5); //Creates object of class Refrigerator
    WashMachines wM1 = new WashMachines("C++","2kg","200rs","49356","TW364","2016","SIEMENS",3000,10); //Creates object of class WashMachines
    WashMachines wM2 = new WashMachines("C++","4kg","250rs","49579","TW376","2016","BOSS",5000,10); //Creates object of class WashMachines
    imandSJList.add(tv1);
    imandSJList.add(tv2);
    imandSJList.add(dvd);
    imandSJList.add(blueray);
    imandSJList.add(cam1);
    imandSJList.add(cam2);
    gamJList.add(c1);
    gamJList.add(c2);
    applJList.add(f1);
    applJList.add(f2);
    applJList.add(wM1);
    applJList.add(wM2);
   }
}
```

So if any body could suggest a better way, I would be very glad
Thank You

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I do what I described ?

Comment: Code itself is not complete. But you add items to your list, add an itemListener to list, implement :    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // TODO Implement this method
    }
 for this which be callled when item is selected, deselected. You don't need mouselistener and other listener for this case as u added in ur class

Comment: OK but I need another itemListener for the secon JList . Can I do this ?

Comment: Since You can have implemented the interface, you can use same listener i.e this and add same listener to each list. In actionEvent get the source from event and see if its first list or second list or any list

Comment: Can you give an example in the code becaue I cannot understant how can  I use this.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly you can keep on adding listener directly to each list

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

public class JListDemo extends JFrame {

    public JListDemo() {

        setSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        final JLabel label = new JLabel("Update");
        String[] data = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
        final JList dataList = new JList(data);

        dataList.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent arg0) {
                if (!arg0.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
                  label.setText(dataList.getSelectedValue().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        add(dataList);
        add(label);

        setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new JListDemo();
    }

}
```